# gcp cloud function returns 404 when deployed from command line

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

If I deploy the [example hello world](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-go) within the console, the url/trigger works. If I deploy from command line it looks to be exact same code / attributes in cloud functions console, but the url is 404. I can't spot the difference/issue.

The deployed trigger/url shows - "404 page not found" for the below hello world example if deployed this way from command line.

```
gcloud functions deploy hellogo --entry-point=HelloWorld --trigger-http --region=us-central1 --memory=128MB --runtime=go116 --allow-unauthenticated
```

```html
// Package p contains an HTTP Cloud Function.
package p

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// HelloWorld prints the JSON encoded "message" field in the body
// of the request or "Hello, World!" if there isn't one.
func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var d struct {
        Message string `json:"message"`
    }

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&d); err != nil {
        switch err {
        case io.EOF:
            fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello World!")
            return
        default:
            log.Printf("json.NewDecoder: %v", err)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
    }

    if d.Message == "" {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello World!")
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, html.EscapeString(d.Message))
}
```

Comment: Did you include `go.mod`?

Comment: Is there perhaps a more detailed error listed in the GCP logs?

Comment: What is the URL that you test and that return a 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to reproduce your error but couldn't replicate on my end. I've use the same command as yours and I can successfully access the url or call via HTTP trigger the deployed hello world cloud function.

```js
gcloud functions deploy hellogo --entry-point=HelloWorld --trigger-http --region=us-central1 --memory=128MB --runtime=go116 --allow-unauthenticated
```

Output of successful curl:

[image]

I suggest you check the url you're trying to access since according to this GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#login):

> If you attempt to invoke a function that does not exist, Cloud Functions responds with an HTTP/2 302 redirect which takes you to the Google account login page. This is incorrect. It should respond with an HTTP/2 404 error response code. The problem is being addressed.

The solution

> Make sure you specify the name of your function correctly. You can
> always check using gcloud functions call which returns the correct 404
> error for a missing function.

You can also refer to this complete [guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-go) to quickstart your CF creation and deployment using the Go runtime.

Comment: Yes, I did check functions name, I was logged in,  and was using the guide in quickstart that is linked in question etc. These weren't my issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and

1. Deleted the cloud function
2. Created it again

And the 404 disappeared.
My guess is that google creates the function and the http trigger separately and, in some cases, the trigger creation fails silently. It's very disturbing because there's nothing visible on the cloud console.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, my project where I got stuck has more code in it than just this function. I went down this path after trying to deploy a single function/file within larger project. If I simplify down to a folder with just a `hello.go` and `go.mod` indeed it works :-/ to deploy it from command line:

`gcloud functions deploy hellogo --entry-point=HelloWorld --trigger-http --region=us-central1 --memory=128MB --runtime=go116 --allow-unauthenticated`

```
// go.mod

module github.com/nickfoden/hello

go 1.16
```

Thank you for the fast replies and assistance. Rather than try to create a single function within existing project with larger go.sum, multiple folders, existing server/api etc. I am going to start from here having a single file with a cloud function and build on top of it and see at what point/if I get stuck again.

Comment: Did you find any solution with most large code base? I'm really stuck at it also